# Building an SQL query to pinpoint a record in a stack based on "status" and it's chronological order

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how to build a query that will return only 2 of the transaction records from a stack of 1 to many transaction records grouped under one Serial Number. The 2 records I need are;

1) the latest transaction in the stack that has a status of 'ERROR' and 
2) the next most recent transaction in that stack that has a status of "SUCCESS".

So an example set of records could look like this...

```
1)  SERIAL_NUMBER   TRXN_ID     STATUS
    -------------   ---------   --------
1   08LKL47T8ZF6    16379796    Success
2   08LKL47T8ZF6    16380200    Error
3   08LKL47T8ZF6    16381077    Retired
4   08LKL47T8ZF6    16581500    Success
5   08LKL47T8ZF6    16581833    Success
6   08LKL47T8ZF6    16382800    Retired
7   08LKL47T8ZF6    16583505    Error
8   08LKL47T8ZF6    16586413    Error
```

So far I have the following... but this would return all 8 records listed above...

```
SELECT 
         STG.src_serial_number 
        ,STG.trxn_id
        ,STG.interface_status
  FROM 
       staging_table STG 

       -- All SN's where the most recent(max) transaction was an ERROR.
       ,(  SELECT X.src_serial_number
             FROM staging_table X  
                  ,(  SELECT MAXNUM.src_serial_number, max(MAXNUM.trxn_id) as trxn_id
                        FROM staging_table MAXNUM  
                       WHERE MAXNUM.src_serial_number = src_serial_number
                    GROUP BY MAXNUM.src_serial_number ) Y
            WHERE X.src_serial_number = Y.src_serial_number
              AND X.trxn_id = Y.trxn_id
              AND X.interface_status = 'Error'
        ) ERROR_REC

       -- No prior TRXN_ID / trxn for this Serial Number stack is a SUCCESS.
       ,(  SELECT PRIORSUCCESS.src_serial_number
             FROM staging_table PRIORSUCCESS
            WHERE PRIORSUCCESS.interface_status = 'Success' 
              AND PRIORSUCCESS.src_serial_number = src_serial_number
        ) SUCCESS_REC

 WHERE STG.src_serial_number = ERROR_REC.src_serial_number
   AND STG.src_serial_number = SUCCESS_REC.src_serial_number
   AND ERROR_REC.src_serial_number = SUCCESS_REC.src_serial_number

ORDER BY  STG.src_serial_number asc, STG.trxn_id asc
```

Expected results would be to build a query that would return only record #8 (the latest Error) and #5 (the latest Success)

```
    SERIAL_NUMBER   TRXN_ID     STATUS
    -------------   ---------   --------
5   08LKL47T8ZF6    16581833    Success
8   08LKL47T8ZF6    16586413    Error
```

Comment: UNION may make this very simple (MAX/MIN & limit 1)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I don't have much experience with UNIONS. Any chance you could put together a theoretical example?

Answer (score 0):

Not too pretty, but - would it help? Probably won't work too fast if data set is large (mind you, fetching from the same table 3 times!).

```
SQL> with test (rn, serial, trxn_id, status) as
  2  (
  3  select 1,   '08LKL47T8ZF6',    16379796,    'Success' from dual union all
  4  select 2,   '08LKL47T8ZF6',    16380200,    'Error'   from dual union all
  5  select 3,   '08LKL47T8ZF6',    16381077,    'Retired' from dual union all
  6  select 4,   '08LKL47T8ZF6',    16581500,    'Success' from dual union all
  7  select 5,   '08LKL47T8ZF6',    16581833,    'Success' from dual union all
  8  select 6,   '08LKL47T8ZF6',    16382800,    'Retired' from dual union all
  9  select 7,   '08LKL47T8ZF6',    16583505,    'Error'   from dual union all
 10  select 8,   '08LKL47T8ZF6',    16586413,    'Error'   from dual
 11  )
 12  select * from test
 13  where trxn_id = (select max(trxn_id) from test
 14                   where status = 'Error'
 15                  )
 16     or trxn_id = (select max(trxn_id) from test
 17                   where status = 'Success'
 18                     and trxn_id < (select max(trxn_id) from test
 19                                    where status = 'Error'
 20                                   )
 21                  );

        RN SERIAL          TRXN_ID STATUS
---------- ------------ ---------- -------
         5 08LKL47T8ZF6   16581833 Success
         8 08LKL47T8ZF6   16586413 Error

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the feedback so far. @LittleFoot, I think the above solution is not realistic, unless I'm understanding it wrong. My table for which I need to pull data from (STAGING_TABLE) has 9.5 million rows and growing each day. UNION'ing each row of data would be impossible. This is what I have built so far, but it is soooooooo slow...

```
  SELECT STG_SUB.src_serial_number
    FROM staging_table STG_SUB
   WHERE STG_SUB.interface_status = 'Error'
     AND STG_SUB.record_id = ( SELECT MAX(MAX_TRXN.record_id)
                                 FROM staging_table MAX_TRXN
                                WHERE MAX_TRXN.src_serial_number = STG_SUB.src_serial_number )
UNION
  SELECT STG_SUB.src_serial_number
    FROM staging_table STG_SUB
   WHERE STG_SUB.record_id = ( SELECT MAX(MAX_TRXN.record_id)
                                 FROM staging_table MAX_TRXN
                                WHERE MAX_TRXN.src_serial_number = STG_SUB.src_serial_number
                                  AND MAX_TRXN.interface_status = 'Success'
MINUS
  SELECT STG_SUB.src_serial_number
    FROM staging_table STG_SUB
   WHERE STG_SUB.interface_status <> 'Error'
     AND STG_SUB.record_id = ( SELECT MAX(MAX_TRXN.record_id)
                                 FROM staging_table MAX_TRXN
                                WHERE MAX_TRXN.src_serial_number = STG_SUB.src_serial_number )
ORDER BY 1
```